# Get all processes for Current User

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, wmi, win32-process

I need to get all processes for current user. Currently I have a function implemented using WMI that gets all active processes by All Users. I need to somehow get all processes by Current User.

If you go to Task Manager in Windows, Details tab, you will see all processes by All Users. But say you are in Visual Studio and you go to Debug/Attach To Process, this shows all processes by Current User. That's the list that I need.

Here is my solution of All Processes by All Users:

```
    CComPtr<IEnumWbemClassObject> pEnumerator;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"),
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);
```

Either a WMI or Win32 solution will be good enough. Thank you!!

Comment: When enumerating the processes, check the owner using the `GetOwner` method.

Comment: @CodyGray, thank you. I will try it. Hopefully it will work. How do you I make your answer as a solution. I do not want the question to remain open.

Comment: @CodyGray this returns the domain/username of the active process that is currently running. I want to get All The Processes running under the current User. This won't help me. Sorry.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It can't. [It returns the owner of the process you've enumerated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390460.aspx). Clearly I do not understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, there is now short way. But here is the working solution if anyone is interested:

```
std::wstring GetProcessUserName(DWORD dwProcessId)
{
    HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwProcessId);
    if (processHandle != NULL)
    {
        HANDLE tokenHandle;
        if (OpenProcessToken(processHandle, TOKEN_READ, &tokenHandle))
        {
            TOKEN_USER tokenUser;
            ZeroMemory(&tokenUser, sizeof(TOKEN_USER));
            DWORD tokenUserLength = 0;

            PTOKEN_USER pTokenUser;
            GetTokenInformation(tokenHandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS::TokenUser, NULL,      
            0, &tokenUserLength);
            pTokenUser = (PTOKEN_USER) new BYTE[tokenUserLength];

            if (GetTokenInformation(tokenHandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS::TokenUser, pTokenUser, tokenUserLength, &tokenUserLength))
            {
                TCHAR szUserName[_MAX_PATH];
                DWORD dwUserNameLength = _MAX_PATH;
                TCHAR szDomainName[_MAX_PATH];
                DWORD dwDomainNameLength = _MAX_PATH;
                SID_NAME_USE sidNameUse;
                LookupAccountSid(NULL, pTokenUser->User.Sid, szUserName, &dwUserNameLength, szDomainName, &dwDomainNameLength, &sidNameUse);
                delete pTokenUser;
                return std::wstring(szUserName);
            }
        }
    }

    return std::wstring();
}

std::unordered_map<std::wstring, std::vector<DWORD>> GetAllRunningProcessesForCurrentUser()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::wstring, std::vector<DWORD>> processHash;

    HRESULT hres;

    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        return processHash;
    }

    do {
        // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

        CComPtr<IWbemLocator> pLoc;
        hres = pLoc.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator);
        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            break;
        }

        // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method
        // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
        // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
        // to make IWbemServices calls.
        CComPtr<IWbemServices> pSvc;
        hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
        NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
        NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
        0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
        NULL,                    // Security flags.
        0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
        0,                       // Context object 
        &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
        );

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            break;
        }

        // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------
        hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
        NULL,                        // Server principal name 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
        NULL,                        // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
        );

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            break;
        }

        // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

        CComPtr<IEnumWbemClassObject> pEnumerator;
        hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"),
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            break;
        }

        // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

        CComPtr<IWbemClassObject> pclsObj;
        while (pEnumerator)
        {
            ULONG uReturn = 0;
            HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

            if (0 == uReturn)
            {
                break;
            }

            VARIANT vtProp;
            VARIANT vtProp2;

            hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            hr = pclsObj->Get(L"ProcessId", 0, &vtProp2, NULL, NULL);

            auto userName = GetProcessUserName(vtProp2.intVal);

            TCHAR szActiveUserName[_MAX_PATH];
            DWORD dwActiveUserNameLength = _MAX_PATH;
            GetUserName(szActiveUserName, &dwActiveUserNameLength);

            if (_tcscmp(userName.c_str(), szActiveUserName) == 0)
            {
                processHash[vtProp.bstrVal].push_back(vtProp2.intVal);
            }


            VariantClear(&vtProp2);
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            pclsObj.Release();
        }
    } while (false);

    CoUninitialize();

    return processHash;
}
```

Comment: I have one comment. Why do you get the active user name again, and again, and again? That code should be positioned before the do while loop. This sort of thing you should only do once.

Comment: @BenKey I agree with you. I cleaned it up afterwards. It's just that when it worked I decided to post it right away. There are also memory leaks int he code. Handles are not being closed.